# Element not clickable - error work around not working as expected using Python and Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

While trying to scrape review data from tripadvisor's new website, am trying to click on the more button to expand the reviews before picking them up. The code works fine on the first page, but throws error on the subsequent pages.
Here's the part of code that I am using:

```
for num in range(page_count):
    try:
        if num != 0:
            try:
                nxt = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.arrowNav.taLnk")))
                #nxt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk")
                nxt.click()
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            except NoSuchElementException:
                print("this is a NEE1")
                driver.refresh()
                nxt = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.arrowNav.taLnk")))
                #actions = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(nxt).click().perform()
                driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            except WebDriverException:
                print("this is a WDE1")
                #nxt = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.nav.next.rndBtn.ui_button.primary.taLnk")
                nxt = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.nav.next.arrowNav.taLnk")))
                actions = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(nxt)
                driver.implicitly_wait(2)
                actions.click()
                actions.perform()
        try:
            more = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")))
            #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'loadingWhiteBox'))
            #more = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")
            #more.location_once_scrolled_into_view
            #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", more)
            more.click()
            time.sleep(1)
        except TimeoutException:
            print("There is no 'more' button on page %d" % (num+1))
        except WebDriverException:
            print("this is a WDE2")
            more = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")
            more = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")))
            #more.location_once_scrolled_into_view
            #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", more)
            #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, "loadingWhiteBox"))
#            actions = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(more)
#            driver.implicitly_wait(2)
#            actions.click()
#            actions.perform()
            time.sleep(1)

        review_result = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'entry')))
        review_date = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.ratingDate.relativeDate").get_attribute('title')

        with open('input.txt', 'a') as fid:
            for date,review in zip(review_date,review_result):
                         fid.write(unidecode(review_date))
                         fid.write(sep1)
                         fid.write(unidecode(review.text))
                         fid.write(sep)
                         fid.write(line_break)
```

Below is the error:

```
> WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <span class="taLnk
> ulBlueLinks"
> onclick="ta.prwidgets.call('handlers.clickCollapse',event,this);">...</span>
> is not clickable at point (292, 615). Other element would receive the
> click: <div class="loadingWhiteBox"></div>
```

I looked up to a number of posts related to same issues and found out few work around for the error and tried them all. The only thing that seemed to be working was using ActionChains, which is currently uncommented in the code. It doesn't throws any error but it wouldn't actually click on the more button and expand the reviews. Moreover, the code processes till a certain page and then get stuck on the same page till the loop ends picking same reviews again and again. I am unable to find any solution for this issue. Please help.

The element is attached to the tag

> span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks

Comment: can you give a url to the website

Comment: url: [link](https://www.tripadvisor.in/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like loading white box web element is overlapping the more button. From your code, I have seen the code to wait for invisibility of white box. Please put this code before clicking on more button as given below.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, 'loadingWhiteBox')) 
more =driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.taLnk.ulBlueLinks")
more.click()
```

Please try to increase the timeout if you get timeout exception.

Comment: Oh yes, this was my bad. I should check for the invisibility before looking for the element to be clicked. This worked for me!

Comment: There is another problem associated with this - when I click on the more button, it only expands the first review. Whereas all the more buttons on the page have same tag as I have used. Earlier it used to expand all the reviews in a go but now it just expands the first one. Could you help me around that!

Answer (score 1):

This occurs due to page refresh or changes when driver attempt to perform action on the element. The location of the element has changed after the driver has stored its reference and now some other element is present at the desired location

We may use Javascript to scroll to that particular element and the perform the action:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id_of_element"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

Comment: I already tried this in my code, didn't work. Still got the same error.

Comment: Then there must be some other element overlapping the element you want to click. Checkout for that